# PHPUnit assertEquals strict type check

Tags: php, phpunit, assertion

My objective is to ensure that an object graph has expected values and types. I want to ensure every value is of the expected type.

To this end, `assertEquals()` is unfortunately not useful:

```
$this->assertEquals(
    [ 'prop' => '0' ],
    [ 'prop' => 0 ]
);
// -> no failures
```

In this case, `assertSame()` works nicely:

```
$this->assertSame(
    [ 'prop' => '0' ],
    [ 'prop' => 0 ]
);
// Failed asserting that Array &0 (
//     'prop' => 0
// ) is identical to Array &0 (
//     'prop' => '0'
// ).
```

The problem with `assertSame()` is that it also checks reference for objects:

```
$this->assertSame(
    (object) [ 'prop' => 0 ],
    (object) [ 'prop' => 0 ]
);
// Failed asserting that two variables reference the same object.
```

What options do I have?

---

On a separate note, I'm not sure why this was designed in this way - to me it feels that `assertSame()` does two things at once (I've have at most verified object class, not references).

Comment: `assertSame()` is designed for checking if "two variables reference the same object" -  **not** that they are the same, but just if it is the same reference or not - here you are explicitly creating 2 objects - each has internally different reference.

Comment: @java.web `assertSame()` works differently with objects than other types because it mimics PHP's `===`. `assertSame` is designed to check the type (that's the purpose of `1 === '1'` is false), except objects, where the exact object is expected.
What I asked here is basically consistent behaviour, since I'm not interested if the object reference is the same, but rather that the object type and contents are the same.

Comment: there is no @"java" here ...anyway, I was just pointing out why that approach didn't work

Comment: I'm surprised in 2020 that there is still not an ideal solution for this. Although the solutions offered below do solve the problem, none of them are ideal in asserting that an object's properties all have identical values. I wonder if there is a historical reason for this.

Comment: I'm surprised in 2020 that there is still not a native solution for this in phpunit. Something like $this->assertIdentical() would be ideal. Although the solutions offered below do solve the problem, none of them are ideal in asserting that an object's properties all have identical values (for a variety of reasons). I wonder if there is a historical reason for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So far, I came up with the following option:

```
/**
 * @param mixed $expected
 * @param mixed $actual
 * @param string $message
 */
public function assertObjectGraph($expected, $actual, $message = '')
{
    $expected = $this->convertObjectsToHashes($expected);
    $actual = $this->convertObjectsToHashes($actual);

    $this->assertSame($expected, $actual, $message);
}

/**
 * @param mixed $value
 * @return mixed
 */
private function convertObjectsToHashes($value)
{
    if (is_object($value)) {
        $value = ['__CLASS__' => get_class($value)] + get_object_vars($value);
    }

    if (is_array($value)) {
        $value = array_map([$this, __FUNCTION__], $value);
    }

    return $value;
}
```

Examples:

```
$this->assertObjectGraph(
    (object) [ 'prop' => 0 ],
    (object) [ 'prop' => 0 ]
);
// -> ok

$this->assertObjectGraph(
    (object) [ 'prop' => 0 ],
    (object) [ 'prop' => '0' ],
);
// Failed asserting that Array &0 (
//     '__CLASS__' => 'stdClass'
//     'prop' => '0'
// ) is identical to Array &0 (
//     '__CLASS__' => 'stdClass'
//     'prop' => 0
// ).

class Test{public $prop = 0;}
$this->assertObjectGraph(
    (object) [ 'prop' => 0 ],
    new Test()
);
// Failed asserting that Array &0 (
//     '__CLASS__' => 'Test'
//     'prop' => 0
// ) is identical to Array &0 (
//     '__CLASS__' => 'stdClass'
//     'prop' => 0
// ).
```

Comment: Cool, but my concern here is that you're getting one error message for the entire object. If you have one property in the object (as in your example), then the error message is readable. But if you have hundreds of properties, parsing one long error message to find just one or two differences in the object will be extra work every time the test fails.

Answer (score 0):

You could first check for array key existence then check for correct type, as example:

```
    $this->assertArrayHasKey('prop', $input);
    $this->assertInternalType(\PHPUnit_Framework_Constraint_IsType::TYPE_INT, $input['prop']);
    // or more simply as this->assertTrue(is_int($new_id));
    $this->assertEquals(0, $input['prop']);
```

hope this help

Comment: It's easy when it is a check on one property, but not so much for a whole object graph..

Comment: hi @Christian of course. But in this manner you can directly pointed to the issue (the type instead of the value of a field) rather than a big object graph that differ to another.

Answer (score 0):

As your aim seems to be to compare 2 arrays,

it should be noted that in official PHP manual at - [Array Operators](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php) - there is described support of `===` operator for arrays

> $a === $b Identity    TRUE if $a and $b have the same key/value pairs in
>   the same **order** and of the **same types**. // same types is only for values - does not check key types

So what would you do is to compare result of this in a true assert:

```
$this->assertTrue(['a' => '1', 'b' => '2'] === ['a' => 1, 'b' => '2']);
```

`assertEquals()` fails in your case because it does exactly what it says, it tests with `==` - an `equal` operator which I admit is not really intuitive and brings some funky stuff such as

```
$this->assertEquals(321, true); // this would PASS!
```

As for objects, you should define a whole separate comparator.

Comment: `$this->assertTrue(['a' => '1', 'b' => '2'] === ['a' => 1, 'b' => '2']);` ... yeah, and when that fails with a very complex object/array, what do you get? "Expectation failed, true was expected, but found false" <- not so very useful.


Also, I was quite clear with my intention: I wanted to compare similar objects, especially useful when working with value objects.

The solution I came up with below is still the better version for my scenario...maybe give it a look instead of stating the obvious...

Comment: I am sorry but your Q examples and your A code ends with comparing 2 arrays - so the intention was not so clear for me. However I do agree showing dumps of compared items may come handy, although it is not necessary and you've basically wrote your own comparator - which is I guess the obvious and you should look for how to convert object to array.